# How to display the date in the correct order? (React Native)

Tags: javascript, database, react-native, youtube, timezone

In my mobile app i share my Youtube channel list. Under my Youtube videos the date is not displayed in the correct format 
(the format that appears is the following: month/day/year).

How to display it in french format (day/month/year)?

```js
const VideoListItem = ({ data, onVideoPress }) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onVideoPress(data)}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <CachedImage
          uri={data.artworkUrlHigh.url}
          style={styles.flexMax}
          imageStyle={styles.cover}
        />
        <View style={styles.textContainer}>
          <View style={styles.flexMax}>
            <Text style={styles.text} numberOfLines={2} ellipsizeMode="tail">
              {decode(data.title)}
            </Text>
           
          </View>
          <Text style={styles.textAlt}>
            Publié le{' '}
            {new Date(parseInt(data.publishedAt, 10)).toLocaleDateString('fr-FR', { timezone: 'UTC' })}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Which browser?

Chrome shows 11/07/2019 today in French

```js
var data = {}
data.publishedAt = "1562848984568";
console.log(
  new Date(+data.publishedAt).toLocaleDateString('fr-FR', { timezone: 'UTC' })
)
// US for comparison
console.log(
  new Date(+data.publishedAt).toLocaleDateString('en-US', { timezone: 'UTC' })
)
```

Options and locales on Mobile are not widely supported

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString#Browser_compatibility

[image]

---

**Intl.DateTimeFormat** may work better

```js
var data = {}
data.publishedAt = "1562848984568";
var date = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('fr-FR').format(+data.publishedAt)
console.log(date)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat#Browser_compatibility

[image]

Sure version:

```js
var pad = function(num) { return ("0"+num).slice(-2) }
var format = function(dateString) { 
  var date = new Date(+dateString);
  return pad(date.getDate())+"/"+pad(date.getMonth()+1)+"/"+date.getFullYear();
}

// test:
var data = {}
data.publishedAt = "1562848984568";
console.log(format(data.publishedAt))
// end test

/* 
used like this:

<Text style={styles.textAlt}>Publié le {format(data.publishedAt)}</Text>

*/
```

Comment: I'm only talking about my mobile app (please see the question again.)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Not really. But the answer is likely support for your choice of formatter. I will post two more versions. Version one is ready

Comment: @Leeli what is your app build with?  Is it React Native or Apache Cordova on something else?

Comment: @Eric Villemure with React Native :)

Comment: See update. The last version will work on all JavaScript platforms

Comment: @mplungjan friend I don't use a browser. I share my youtube videos with youtube api, they are directly in my app, so i don't need browser do you understand?

Comment: @mplungjan Well, I thought you were talking about navigator, I don't understand how to put your code in mine lol I'm novice.. :/

Comment: See my last version. You need to copy the functions to elsewhere in your app where such codes live

Comment: Sorry. I tried to help. You need some knowledge yourself I do not have any react-native experience

Answer (score 0):

have you tried [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)? the implementation is simple

`moment(data.publishedAt).format('DD/MM/YYYY')`

so in your code

```
import moment from 'moment'

const VideoListItem = ({ data, onVideoPress }) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onVideoPress(data)}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <CachedImage
          uri={data.artworkUrlHigh.url}
          style={styles.flexMax}
          imageStyle={styles.cover}
        />
        <View style={styles.textContainer}>
          <View style={styles.flexMax}>
            <Text style={styles.text} numberOfLines={2} ellipsizeMode="tail">
              {decode(data.title)}
            </Text>

          </View>
          <Text style={styles.textAlt}>
            Publié le{' '}
            {moment(data.publishedAt).format('DD/MM/YYYY')} <-- this line
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

Comment: I don't know how to do this my friend, I'm novice, can you show me directly with my code please?

Comment: place `import moment from 'moment'` on top of your page. then use it.

Comment: "the development server returned response error code 500"